What do I do when the first column of my characteristic equation for finding eigenvectors are zero?
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}  2 &4 &1\\
    6 &5 &2\\
     3& 1& 0\end{pmatrix}$$
I got the eigenvalues to be $-2,3,-1$ and I've gotten the eigenvectors of the first $2$ eigenvalues. I'm trying to diagonalize $A.$

What is a column of characteristic equation? And if you meant the column of a square matrix, in your example there is no zero column...Please review the instructions to properly write mathematics in this site.
